# É possível transformar validação em erro do formulário no Angular?

Tags: angular, formulário

É até difícil de explicar.
Tenho um formulário que faço uma checagem de um campo se o mesmo é maior que zero. Caso seja, mostro uma mensagem para o usuário.
Quero transformar isso em um erro do formulário, pois, eu só consigo liberar o botão salvar se o formulário estiver sem erro.
Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isso.
Segue meu fonte (não consegui formatar de uma forma que consiga ficar bonitinho aqui):

```html
<form #lancamentoForm="ngForm">
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-3 ui-fluid">
            <label>Valor</label>
            <input pInputText type="text" placeholder="0,00" currencyMask name="valor" #valor="ngModel"
                   [options]="{ prefix: '', thousands: '.', decimal: ',', allowNegative: false }" ngModel>
            <div *ngIf="valor.value <= 0 && valor.dirty" class="ui-message ui-message-error">
              Valor deve ser maior que 0
            </div>
          </div>
<button type="submit" pButton label="Salvar" [disabled]="lancamentoForm.invalid"></button>
</form>
```

Eu quero fazer com que quando houver a mensagem 'Valor maior que 0' o lancamentoForm fique como invalid para o tratamento do botão.
É possível?
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Cara para isso você pode criar uma validação em classe de css que desabilita o botão se o valor for menor ou igual a 0.

E pra isso basta você utilizar o ng-disabled no botão e ficaria próximo a isso:

```
<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="valor.value <= 0 && valor.dirty">Button</button>
```

[Referências](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

Comment: Gostei da ideia Lucas, mas, ai eu teria que fazer uma validação em exclusivo para essa verificação, não é? Já existem outros vários campos que eu já faço um tratamento (por exemplo, pelo required ou minlength) em que o formulário já fica válido ou inválido. Eu gostaria de aproveitar essa checagem 'genérica' e adicionar a minha necessidade deste campo de valor onde eu checo se é maior que 0.